# Google Hangout XML - How to include Drive (Docs) or You-Tube Apps?

Tags: google-apps, google-hangouts

I am a newbie in creating Google Hangouts and using the XML file and API. Could someone explain how to include Drive/Docs or other Google Apps in the navigation bar of a Hangout? I have created the simple hangout app and am trying to customize it. I am using the Developer's Sandbox to open the Hangout. The XML file is deployed on a publicly available server. I want the app to have much of the same functionality as those created using the Google+ starter kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/)? Once you get the basics of how to build a Hangout, each service like Google Drive or YouTube has their own specifics on how to integrate them within a third-party app. You can read more about [YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) and [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/) on the Google Developer Site.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but I have read everything there is to read about creating Hangouts and have concluded there is no way to easily integrate 3rd party and Google apps like You Tube and Drive. What I was hoping to do was create a Hangout similar to the ones you can create using the Google "Start Hangout" that enables applications to be added using the "Add Apps" button on the navigation bar. This would be cool, but I do not think it is possible. You need to use the APIs Console to define them and there does not seem to be a way to do this. Please guide me if you have done this yourself.

Comment: I have built many hangout apps - I am a Developer Advocate working on Hangout Apps. From your comment I cannot determine what you feel is not possible. To create a Hangout App, you go to the developer console, create a new project and enable the Google+ Hangouts service. See the docs for more specific instructions: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/running. Once you do that, you can launch your Hangout using the Hangout Button: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button. Recently used apps will appear at the top of the hangout, like you described.

Comment: I understand how to add Drive functionality using the API, but I was hoping not to have to reinvent the wheel and use the Drive App that is built into the standard Hangout. The API Console project seems to need a reference to Gadget-XML (same as Hangout XML?) on a public website. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, Hangout Apps need to be publish a publicly-available XML. I am not sure how your Drive App works but I don't think a standard Drive App can run in a Hangout. You can, however, use the Drive REST API or the Drive Picker.